# Are the benefits of “Balanced Power” fact or fiction?

Tags: power

Are the benefits of “Balanced Power” fact or fiction?

I have been reading about “Balanced Power” (aka “Technical Power”), but there seems to be a fairly small number of sources for information about it. Here are some links.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-phase_electric_power#Technical_power_.28balanced_power.29

http://www.furmansound.com/product.php?id=IT-20_II

http://www.6moons.com/audioreviews/equitech/1.html

http://www.equitech.com/products/products.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about sound design.

Comment: According to various sources online, it's used in recording studios.

Comment: This seems to sum it up well: "If your noise is all hissy white noise from noisy electronics, balanced power won't do a thing. If your noise is mostly hum from power supply leakage on bad equipment (especially old guitar amps), it can do an amazing job. If it's hum from ground loops, it won't do anything (or anything more than plugging all your equipments to one extension cord). Balanced power is a particular tool to solve a particular problem." Source: http://www.epanorama.net/documents/groundloop/balanced_power.html

Comment: @Corey many things are used in recording studios that don't relate to sound design. Anyway read the link provided by Todd - it probably answers your question although realistically, it's a bandage to fix poorly designed equipment or equipment that is starting the process of failing.